# dispaying Firebase firestore data

Tags: html, firebase

I am trying to make a website alongside my app (made with flutter). I want to be able to display the same information that I display on my profile page on my website. How do I do this? I want to display the

```
user_dob
user_email
user_first_name
user_last_name
user_phone_number
user_addresses
```

those are the names of the fields in Firestore
is there a line that just gets that info?

I don't have any code at all to go off of, so help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you using FlutterFire?

Comment: no, i just want to display the same info on my website

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Flutter _web_ but I know you can use FlutterFire to access Firebase's services in Flutter. Check it out here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_database

Comment: no i think there is a misunderstanding. I am not making my website with flutter. I am using the normal CSS HTML and js. I just want to display info from firestore

Comment: _Oh_  okay.  Also, you say firestore in your comment but you tagged the realtime-database in your question. Can you clarify which one you're using?

Comment: To get started with Firebase Realtime Database on the web, have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start. If you're using Firestore, start here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: yes i am using cloud firestore

Comment: i apologize for the confusion

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen comment is the way to go, goodluck!